# How to test a text parsing program

Tags: python, parsing, testing

I am writing a program in Python that is basically grabbing data from a file (could be csv, excel or some vendor EDI file) with over a thousand lines and converting the data into a new format and outputting the file.  So maybe I am reading data from a CSV file and outputting the same data into JSON format.  How do I test that my program is correctly converting the data?  Should I write a new program that reads item from both input and output files and see if they match?

Comment: I think this is too broad to be answered well. It seems like you are asking: how do I write tests in python? There are entire books devoted to this. [pytest](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/) is a common framework for testing that would allow you to write tests. How you write tests will depend a lot on how your code is organized. As you gain experience you might find that how you test will start influencing how you organize your code.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of program is quite easy to test, because it is a pure computation without any real time interactions with anything. It doesn't have to talk to servers, or respond to interrupts, or interact in real time with specialized hardware.

You can test it with known input/output pairs. Feed it each input, and check that the expected output is produced.

Design the inputs to exercise all the cases that may occur: every variation in the syntax being parsed, in isolation, and in combination with others.

You can write some or all of these tests before the code which satisfies them is written or completed, then work on the code to get the tests to pass.

A parser should also fail somehow on bad input, and that should be tested. If you test only that good inputs produce good results, it may be that bad inputs produce some sort of result without failing. When the program is deployed, it is then not helpful to the user who happens to have prepared or obtained bad input. The program runs successfully, and the garbage which is produced makes it on to the next processing stage.

Basically in every place in the code where you are handling two or more input cases, if the case handling is not complete (every possibility is covered), then the possibilities which are not handled should go to a "catch all" case which produces a loud failure, like an exception being thrown.

Comment: I don't have known input output pairs I just have the input file what then?

Comment: @bakalolo Aha, good question! The input output pairs are something you must produce yourself. Some of the example inputs could come from the real input file, but it's better if you set that aside and use your intelligence to come up with the test cases which specifically target all the functionality of the parser.  If the input file always has at least two fields of CSV, then it doesn't test whether the parser handles just one field, or zero fields. Real inputs don't always have the variety to predict all that can happen; you want confidence that this will work on unknown future inputs.